# Crashing the sha1() function in PHP?

Tags: hash, php, sha, code-review, ctf

I am working on the following war game from **Defend The Web**, which requires me to do a source code review to login as the user `memtash`. The code is on GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/DefendTheWeb/foss-login/-/blob/master/class.user.php).

Here is my methodology:

1. Reset the password for user `memtash` which causes memtash’s password to be set to 0 (look at the `password = 0` in the below snippet).

   ```
   $st = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE users SET `reset` = :reset,
   password = 0 WHERE uid = :uid LIMIT 1');
   ```
2. During login, use the username `memtash` and find a value that the PHP `sha1()` function will output as 0 (or a long line of 0’s) to successfully login.

   ```
   if ($row && $row->password == sha1($pass)) {
   ```

How can I make the PHP function `sha1()` return zero, or a list of zeros? One approach is to cause the function to fail making it return false (which is 0), or find an input which when hashed outputs a string value of just zeros.

It will result in a successful login because in PHP these both evaluate to true:

`0 == false`

`0 == 00000000000000000000000000000000`

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to crash the hashing function, or where to get an input which when hashed outputs just zeros?

Even if this is not the correct solution, I think it is a good find!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Since this is a "learning challenge", I'll present the answer as a "guide" to finding the answer, instead of just straight up telling you what the solution is.

You were actually very close to finding the solution, to the point where you identified all the components necessary for exploitation. You seem to miss just the final step, so let's walk through it step by step.

#### Password Reset

When I perform a source code review or penetration test, I always look out for "weirdness". Code, that doesn't quite seem standard. In this case, what first tripped me up was the `reset()` function. Let's have a look at the rough structure here. I'll abbreviate it so we can see the relevant details.

```
// $username is fully in our control
private function reset($username) {
    $user = getUserForUsername($username)

    if($user) {
        $token = generateToken()
        $user->resetToken = $token
        $user->passwordHash = 0

        sendResetLink($user->email, $user->resetToken)
    }
}
```

Doesn't it seem weird, that the password is reset the moment we *request* a password reset, rather than once the email is confirmed? That means, as soon as we know a username (in our case `memtash`), we can reset that user's password hash to 0.

#### Login

So now, you've reached the point where you want to login. Let's look at that code now, which I will abbreviate again:

```
// $username and $password are fully under our control
private function login($username, $password) {
    $user = getUserForUsername($username)

    if($user && $user->passwordHash == sha1($password)) {
        win();
    }
}
```

This is a remarkably small function, and you are right in suspecting that the `sha1()` function should be manipulated somehow.

Your intuition of making it either return `false` or `00000000000000000000000000000000` is on the right track - painfully close, in fact. But let's have a look at the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php):

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns the sha1 hash as a string.

That means that the `sha1()` function will *always* return a hash as a string, and never `false`.

But what about an all-zero hash? In theory, you could find an input that hashes to all-zeroes. In practice, none have been found (or at least, made public).

So that is no good. However, there is something else we can exploit: [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

#### Type Juggling

Type Juggling is a <s>bug</s> feature in PHP, which automatically treats types as other types, supposedly to "aid" developers in doing what they "meant" to do, but most often introducing bugs, that are *very* hard to find unless you know where to look.

PHP has two different operators to compare for equality, `==` and `===`. For the sake of readability, I will call the former "weak comparison" and the latter "strict comparison".

When performing a strict comparison, PHP first checks if the types of both variables are the same, before actually checking for equality. That means something like `<int> === <string>` will *always* be false, because integers are not strings, regardless of their values.

When performing weak comparison, PHP will perform Type Juggling, and bizarrely, will try to cast everything to an integer, if possible.

For some of these, this almost makes sense. For example, `0 == "0"` should evaluate to true, which it does. But PHP's "string to integer" conversion rules are also very strange. For example, the string `"123abc"` evaluates to the integer `123`, at least in PHP 5.

What does all of this mean? We need to find a string, which - when converted to an integer by PHP - would evaluate to `0`.

#### Exponential Notation

Luckily, PHP supports exponential notation, such as `1.23e4` to represent 1.23 * 10^4 (1.23 * 10*10*10*10), or 12300. So what would `0e4` be? 0 * 10^4, which is 0.

In fact, regardless of which number we place after the exponent, it will always evaluate to 0. So "0e29823758752983759283750" would also be 0.

Now we're getting closer to the answer. We need to find a SHA-1 hash, which has the following format: <sup>1</sup>

- 1st Digit: 0
- 2nd Digit: e
- 3rd to 40th Digit: [0-9]

You have several ways of finding inputs that generate such hashes. You can either write a script to brute-force them, or you can just google for them. One such input would be `10932435112`. This would actually be remarkably fast to brute force. You can see that the result of `sha1("10932435112")` is `"0e07766915004133176347055865026311692244"` - which fits perfectly.

And indeed, if you write `var_dump(0 == sha1("10932435112"))`, the result will be `true`. Magical! Hence why these are called "magic hashes".

#### A Recap

This may have gone a bit fast, so I will try to recap each step a bit more succinctly:

First, we notice that we can reset the *hash* of the password to 0 when we call the reset function.

Next, we realize that the relevant code, that checks for successful login is `$hash == sha1($input)`.

Because `$hash` has been set to 0, we need to find a SHA-1 hash, which evaluates to 0.

Because of the weak comparison, PHP will try to convert string inputs (such as the SHA-1 hash) to integers. Furthermore, PHP will honor "exponential notation" when evaluating integers.

We know that, in exponential notation, 0 times any number is 0. Therefore, we need to find a hash, which begins with `0e` followed by only digits.

This an input, which generates such a hash, can either be brute-forced, or looked up. When looking it up, you will find that `sha1("10932435112") == "0e07766915004133176347055865026311692244"`

When comparing `0 == "0e07766915004133176347055865026311692244"`, you will find that *all* PHP versions evalue this to true.

---

<sup>1</sup>: In PHP 5, it's even easier, since any "non-digit" after the exponent is simpy ignored, so "0e1foobar..." would also evaluate to 0. But by using only digits, the exploit works in PHP 7 and beyond as well.

Comment: So I hope this little write-up was useful to you. I felt like I wasn't spoiling *too* much of the challenge, since you have basically already solved it and were just missing the final step. In the future, whenever you see `if(0 == hash($input))`, you can be virtually certain that that part is vulnerable.

Comment: In PHP, like Perl and nearly all other computer languages back to Fortran, 10e4 is 10x(10^4) =10x(10x10x10x10) = 100,000 and 0e4 is 0x(10^4) = 0. The difference might be clearer with 2e4 which is 2x(10x10x10x10) = 20,000 not 2x2x2x2 = 16.

Comment: I was thinking, is exponential notation even needed there? If as you said, `123abc` turns into `123`, something like `0abc` or even just `abc` should compare equal to zero. On a quick test with https://onlinephp.io, they do just that, up to PHP 7.4. But in PHP 8.x `intval("0abc")` does give a zero, but `0 == "0abc"` is false. So yeah, you do seem to need that trick with the exponential in recent versions.

Comment: @ilkkachu In PHP 5, you are absolutely correct. In PHP 7 and onwards, it sadly is.

Comment: Very nice answer, but you might want to update your answer as sha1() will return false if it fails, it is not mentioned in the documentation for some reason and failure is unlikely given it is a widely used and tested function. Also, I think your last sentence is incorrect, newer versions of PHP will throw an exception?

Comment: I just want to note that Exponential notation does not work mathematically like you wrote -  7e4 means 7 * 10^4. Your example of 10e4 is 10 * 10^4 = 100,000. It doesn't change the result of 0e with arbitrary digits being 0

Comment: @user49822, the [online man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) says it returns "the sha1 hash as a string" period, no provision for returning "false". It should be able to deal with arbitrary input strings anyway, so not much there it could fail for. Though technically there's an upper limit to the length of string that can be hashed, but that's 2^64, so meeting the limit would be slightly problematic.

Comment: In PHP 5 and prior (past EOL for 4 years), comparing zero with any string starting with 0 and its second character being a non-digit would evaluate to true. Through PHP 7 (EOL since 2 months ago), a string with 0, then an "e", then a digit, then any other content would would evaluate to true. With PHP 8, it would have to be a string that starts with "0e", then have only digits following it. — Chances of a random sha1 input matching in PHP 5 are 5:128. In PHP 7 are 5:2048. Chances in PHP 8 are much lower, but not heat-death-of-the-universe low. Use a key stretching algorithm, not hashes.

Comment: Specifically I belive the probability would be (1/16)² * (10/16)³⁸ which wolfram alpha tells me is about 6 * 10⁻¹¹. Trivial to brute force on a modern computer

Comment: @Ghedipunk Or, much better, use `===` or set the value to null instead of zero.

Comment: @MamaRaikou Do all three :)

Comment: ```For example, the string "123abc" evaluates to the integer 123, at least in PHP 5.``` - this is true all the way to PHP7.4 - but it's no longer true as of PHP8.0.0.